# How to create a layout with 3 columns with Bootstrap3 like this?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I have 3 columns named `Left`,`Main` and `Right`, and I want them to arranged like this:

MD:

```
Left(3)|Main(6)|Right(3)
```

SM:

```
Main(12)
Left(6)|Right(6)
```

XS:

```
Main(12)
Left(12)
Right(12)
```

And here's my code:

```
<div id="main-content" class="col-xs-12 co-md-offset-3 col-md-6">
</div>
<div id="left-sidebar" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0 pull-left">
</div>
<div id="right-sidebar" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-md-offset-0">
</div>
```

However, the layout of `Main` column is incorrect under the MD mode. So what's the correct code?

(ps: If possible, it's better to put the `Main` div on top of the document.)

Thanks.

Comment: Columns should be inside a `.row` element, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Oh yes, I have unwrapped the outer div with class `row`, and it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `push` `pull` like this..

```
    <div class="row">
        <div id="main-content" class="col-xs-12 col-md-push-3 col-md-6">main
        </div>
        <div id="left-sidebar" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-md-pull-6">left
        </div>
        <div id="right-sidebar" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3">right
        </div>
    </div>
```

Demo: http://codeply.com/go/rWmJU4aNds

Comment: By the way, the class of `main-content` should be `col-md-push-3` not `co-md-push-3`.

Comment: Actually.. the push/pull markup was wrong. I've update the answer

Comment: Except for the `col-md-push-3` in `main` which should be `col-md-push-6`, everything is alright. I've tested it. What's wrong?